# How do i get data from excel using sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of workers on an excel sheet, with the fields (ID (worker identification number in the company), Name, Nickname, Date of Birth, Function (If you are a machine manager, if it is equipment management. ..), Importance (Each function has a different importance, if it is a machine operator has more importance than the receptionist)).

And what I want to do is to make a query that goes to excel sheet to draw 4 workers, returning the Name, Nickname and Function.

The draw must be made by the importance of the worker.

Those who have the highest degree of importance are more likely to be drawn.

Comment: What do you mean by draw? And what logic are you using to draw 4?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I need to get around 4 officials so they can take a test so that they can see if these 4 officials are not committing any crime, since officials are very likely to get lame.The company can not take unnecessary risks.

Comment: I´m using SQL Server, 
Sorry, It was my mistake.

Comment: So a "random" selection of 4 at a time - any rule for not repeating on subsequent runs?

Comment: The employee can only go out once, the 4 employees are always different.

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting, maybe give it a look:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321686/how-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server

Never thought this would be possible. Well, the more you know.

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is not directly possible using query.
You have to use some third party library like iTextSharp or Aspose to do this.

Comment: But can not you do it any other way without having to use libraries?

Comment: I am using Aspose.cell to work with Excel data. you can get a trial version of aspose library. Compare to iTextSharp Aspose is easier to work with.